# Can I split mapped Item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{
    props.preLoaderVisibilty ? <tr><td colSpan="4"><Preloader /></td></tr>
    :
    props.records.map((records, index) =>
        <tr key={index}>
            <td>{records.ticker}</td>
            <td>{records.record_date}</td>
            <td>{records.EPS}</td>
            <td>{records.dividend_cash}%</td>
            <td>{records.dividend_stock}%</td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

I want to split {records.record_date} value like 2020-02-19T18:00:00.000Z to 2020-02-19

Comment: Hello, Have you tried `<td>{records.record_date.split('T')[0]}</td>` ?

Comment: Just to mention that "converting" the date this way - by splitting and only getting the first part is not the correct way. For some people the time of 18:00 could mean a day back, forward from the date you mentioned - because of time zones. I suggest using moment.js to handle this - you can convert any date format to whatever you want.

Comment: I tried this but probably misspelled. Thanks a lot, It worked smoothly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

since the date value will be always in first 10 characters ,you can take the first 10 characters form the string

```
<td>{records.record_date.substring(0 , 9)}</td>
```

or if its not always 10 characters you can do this

```
<td>{records.record_date.substring(0 , records.record_date.indexOf("T"))}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Strongly recommend using the `moment.js` library for converting date into the format you want to render to the view. Install moment.js with npm or yarn:

`npm install moment`

Then import it at the top of your react code:

`import moment from 'moment';`

Then simply use it in your code like such to convert date to your desired format:

`moment(records.record_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: downloading a library just to convert a date to a string with some required format?

Comment: @rags2riches it's not just a converting, you're losing the time  and you can show a wrong date with the simple conversion depending on the timezone of the user.

Comment: Yes I understand that very well and have no issues with that at all. However, the requirement does not request a conversion based on timezone. You may have an app that only focuses on a specific market where timezone conversion is not needed.

Comment: I am fetching the data not showing time zone so I think I don't need moment js in this case

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous comments, you may not want to split on "T" and then get the first index of the array to return.

If you don't mind the format, you could simply use `toDateString()` method, like this:

```
const date = new Date().toDateString();
// Wed Dec 02 2020

records.record_date.toDateString()
```

No need to split.

If this answer helps you solving the issue, **consider** upvoting or accepting it as answer. Thanks.